# delay en formulario con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo un formulario que al dar error te hace esperar 10 segundos para volver a intentarlo.

Este es el codigo que estoy usando:

HTML:

```
<form id="login-form" method="post" class="form-signin" role="form" action="/recordarcontrasena">
    <ul>
        <li class="iconousuario"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></li>
        <li><input readonly tabindex="1" name="email" id="email" type="email" class="fontAwesome" placeholder="&#xf0e0 Correo electrónico" autofocus></li>
        <li><button tabindex="2" class="boton" type="submit" id="Enviar" data-loading-text="Iniciando....">Restablecer Contraseña</button></li>
</form>
```

JS:

```
spop({
    template: '<?=$error; ?><br/>Espere <strong id="CuentaAtras">10</strong> para volver a intentarlo',
    style: 'error', autoclose: 10000 });

$("#login-form").submit(function() {
    spop({ template: 'Tate quieto.', style: 'notice', autoclose: 1000 });
    return false;
});

var timeleft = 10;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("CuentaAtras").textContent = timeleft;
    if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        $('#email').delay(11800).prop('readonly', false);
        $("#login-form").submit(function() { return true; });
    }
},1000);
```

El caso es que con lo que tengo consigo parar el envío del formulario y muestro un mensaje emergente que dice el error que se ha producido y que te esperes 10 segundos.

De momento el desactivar el input email y el botón de enviar el formulario, funciona perfectamente, pero a la hora de volver a activar el envío del formulario no funciona y no termino de entender el motivo.

¿Que puedo tener mal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza:

```
$("#login-form").off('submit');
```

Para quitar el handler que agregaste para prevenir hacer submit.

De otra forma simplemente estas agregando mas handlers para el mismo evento.